# Can you help translate the scroll seal (Characters identified: 神龍圖 嘯天)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

[image]

I believe this dragon is about shinlong but I would like to know the artist as I cannot make up any of the symbols

Answer (score 1):

神龍圖 must be the title of the scroll which means 'paint of the sacred dragon'.

And 嘯天 must be the signature of the artist for the red stamp is also 嘯天, which is simply the name of the artist. Translating it by the word, it could be 'roar towards the sky'.